# Konsole missing menu items

Tags: kde, konsole

The Settings menu usually contain many more items (Configure Shortcuts for one). What happened here?

I tried:

```
aptitude remove --purge konsole; aptitude install konsole
aptitude dist-upgrade
```

none of which helped.

The system is a newly installed Linux Mint Xfce 17.3.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If started from a shell I get:

```
konsole(4906) KXMLGUIClient::loadStandardsXmlFile: ui/ui_standards.rc not found in ("/home/tange/.kde/share/config/", "/etc/kde4/", "/usr/share/kde4/config/")
```

So it is missing a file, which is installed using:

```
sudo aptitude install kdelibs5-data
```

In other words: This is a dependency problem. Probably only visible because I run `konsole` but not KDE.